# Is there a more efficient way to retrieve rows with a list column which includes values in a list? ( either a subset, union, or superset )

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

working with a pandas.dataframe, such that:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 685 entries, 7789285 to 8009947
Data columns (total 18 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype              
---  ------            --------------  -----              
 0   sourcedId         685 non-null    string             
 1   status            685 non-null    string             
 2   dateLastModified  685 non-null    datetime64[ns, UTC]
 3   username          685 non-null    string             
 4   userIds           685 non-null    object             
 5   enabledUser       685 non-null    string             
 6   givenName         685 non-null    string             
 7   familyName        685 non-null    string             
 8   middleName        685 non-null    string             
 9   role              685 non-null    string             
 10  identifier        685 non-null    string             
 11  email             685 non-null    string             
 12  sms               685 non-null    string             
 13  phone             685 non-null    string             
 14  agents            685 non-null    object             
 15  orgs              685 non-null    object             
 16  grades            685 non-null    object             
 17  password          685 non-null    string             
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1), object(4), string(13)
memory usage: 101.7+ KB
df.head()
```

The 'grades' column contains a list of integers as strings, i.e., ['9','10'].  I am able to filter for single values by

```
mask = df.grades.apply(lambda x: '10' in x)
```

In my test dataset, which is created from a list of list that I populate manually, I used integer values so below works just fine(?) *( assume for the sake of argument that the data is a list of integers rather than a list of strings )*

```
gradeList = [9,10]
mask = df.grades.apply(lambda x: any(map(lambda x,y: x==y,x gradeList)))
df[mask].head()
```

I'm relatively new to Python ( over the last five years I've accumulated what I would consider to be about six-to-eight months worth of Python experience, if that ) and completely new to Pandas.  I only have a tenative grasp of list comprehension and the map function.

I had intended the above to allow me to retrieve any records for which a subset of **gradesList** was present in the **grades** column.  For a single integer in **grade**, this is accomplished via:

```
mask = df.grades.apply(lambda x: grade in x)
```

Instead of accomplishing my goal with the above nested lambdas and map, I've created something in which the order of terms in the query parameters ( **gradesList** ) is significant.  Below is the output from my testing script, which operates on test data included in the output. I'm trying not to assume an order for either list...

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------     --------------  -----
 0   id         10 non-null     object
 1   email      10 non-null     object
 2   fullName   10 non-null     object
 3   jobTitles  10 non-null     object
 4   grades     10 non-null     object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 528.0+ bytes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          id                 email          fullName                                          jobTitles           grades
0    smithsm    smithsm@aplace.com         Stu Smith  [developer, licensed pretend nurse, worthless ...  [9, 10, 11, 12]
1   mullenjb   mullenjb@aplace.com      Jason Mullen               [printer guy, supervisor, senior it]         [11, 12]
2    swainrl    swainrl@aplace.com        Ryan Swain                      [nap taker, goof-off, goober]          [9, 10]
3  rankinsns  rankinsns@aplace.com  Nicholas Rankins                           [manual tesla autopilot]          [9, 10]
4  carlsonrm  carlsonrm@aplace.com      Ryan Carlson                     [technician, snarky so-and-so]         [10, 11]
5     ragomv     ragomv@aplace.com         Mike Rago                                  [nice guy, swole]             [10]
6    smithdl    smithdl@aplace.com       David Smith                                         [old hand]              [9]
7  kappleraj  kappleraj@aplace.com   Allison Kappler      [girl coder, definitely not prettier than me]             [11]
8   iresonss   iresonss@aplace.com      Sandy Ireson                                      [hard worker]             [12]
9  conklincc  conklincc@aplace.com     Caleb Conklin                              [millenial magnum pi]          [12, 9]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
query for 'developer'
        id               email   fullName                                          jobTitles           grades
0  smithsm  smithsm@aplace.com  Stu Smith  [developer, licensed pretend nurse, worthless ...  [9, 10, 11, 12]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
query for 11
          id                 email         fullName                                          jobTitles           grades
0    smithsm    smithsm@aplace.com        Stu Smith  [developer, licensed pretend nurse, worthless ...  [9, 10, 11, 12]
1   mullenjb   mullenjb@aplace.com     Jason Mullen               [printer guy, supervisor, senior it]         [11, 12]
4  carlsonrm  carlsonrm@aplace.com     Ryan Carlson                     [technician, snarky so-and-so]         [10, 11]
7  kappleraj  kappleraj@aplace.com  Allison Kappler      [girl coder, definitely not prettier than me]             [11]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
query for 10
          id                 email          fullName                                          jobTitles           grades
0    smithsm    smithsm@aplace.com         Stu Smith  [developer, licensed pretend nurse, worthless ...  [9, 10, 11, 12]
2    swainrl    swainrl@aplace.com        Ryan Swain                      [nap taker, goof-off, goober]          [9, 10]
3  rankinsns  rankinsns@aplace.com  Nicholas Rankins                                       [technician]          [9, 10]
4  carlsonrm  carlsonrm@aplace.com      Ryan Carlson                     [technician, snarky so-and-so]         [10, 11]
5     ragomv     ragomv@aplace.com         Mike Rago                                  [nice guy, swole]             [10]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
query for 11,12
          id                 email         fullName                                      jobTitles    grades
1   mullenjb   mullenjb@aplace.com     Jason Mullen           [printer guy, supervisor, senior it]  [11, 12]
7  kappleraj  kappleraj@aplace.com  Allison Kappler  [girl coder, definitely not prettier than me]      [11]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
query for 10,11
          id                 email      fullName                       jobTitles    grades
4  carlsonrm  carlsonrm@aplace.com  Ryan Carlson  [technician, snarky so-and-so]  [10, 11]
5     ragomv     ragomv@aplace.com     Mike Rago               [nice guy, swole]      [10]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
query for 9,10
          id                 email          fullName                                          jobTitles           grades
0    smithsm    smithsm@aplace.com         Stu Smith  [developer, licensed pretend nurse, worthless ...  [9, 10, 11, 12]
2    swainrl    swainrl@aplace.com        Ryan Swain                      [nap taker, goof-off, goober]          [9, 10]
3  rankinsns  rankinsns@aplace.com  Nicholas Rankins                                       [technician]          [9, 10]
6    smithdl    smithdl@aplace.com       David Smith                                         [old hand]              [9]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
query for 10,9
          id                 email       fullName                       jobTitles    grades
4  carlsonrm  carlsonrm@aplace.com   Ryan Carlson  [technician, snarky so-and-so]  [10, 11]
5     ragomv     ragomv@aplace.com      Mike Rago               [nice guy, swole]      [10]
9  conklincc  conklincc@aplace.com  Caleb Conklin           [millenial magnum pi]   [12, 9]
```

Is anyone able to identify ( hopefully the core concept I'm missing ) or point me towards documentation that will help me unravel what's taking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a more lightweight dataframe:

```
>>> df
          id           grades
0    smithsm     [1, 9, 2, 6]  # <- 9
1   mullenjb  [1, 5, 8, 4, 7]
2    swainrl        [4, 2, 9]  # <- 9
3  rankinsns           [5, 2]
4  carlsonrm  [7, 4, 6, 3, 2]  # <- 3
5     ragomv        [6, 1, 5]
6    smithdl  [2, 9, 6, 7, 3]  # <- 3 & 9
7  kappleraj        [9, 5, 8]  # <- 9
8   iresonss  [8, 6, 7, 5, 4]
9  conklincc           [8, 6]
```

How to find grade list [3, 9]?

Explode your column `grades` and find the grade is in the grade list.

```
>>> df.loc[df['grades'].explode().isin([3, 9]).groupby(level=0).any()
          id           grades
0    smithsm     [1, 9, 2, 6]
2    swainrl        [4, 2, 9]
4  carlsonrm  [7, 4, 6, 3, 2]
6    smithdl  [2, 9, 6, 7, 3]
7  kappleraj        [9, 5, 8]
```

Same as:

```
>>> df.loc[df['grades'].explode() \
      .apply(lambda x: x in [3, 9]) \
      .groupby(level=0).any()]`
```

Comment: That's excellent!  The best I've been able to do thus far was to define a function taking two lists as parameters, nesting two for loops against an enumerate() per list, splitting the tuple iterator into an index and value, appending the results of each equality test to a temporary list, then returning any() against the temporary list.

Your solution is much, much nicer.  I'll read the documentation about the explode() function and try to warp my head around the level parameter again